# Can I update python 3.6.3 to 3.6.5, which is the latest, on windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update Python 3.6.3 to 3.6.5 using the **pip** command. But not successful. I want to know if I can update Python with **pip**. Or do I have to download Python 3.6.5 from the website instead?

Comment: I don't think this question is fully duplicate with that question, which is focus on Python 2.x upgrade to 3.x, and this question is focus on Python 3.x upgrade to 3.x.

Comment: @Smiles Thank you a lot.

Comment: why people mark question as duplicate just by seeing the title. this question is quite different from the question that has mentioned duplicate of.

Comment: conda create --name project-env python=3.6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit [python.org](https://www.python.org), download the latest version, and during the installation it will update your python. Updating python via `pip` is not possible.